# Trying to call child's event without calling parents event

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a usercontrol which is embedded in another control. both of these control have their mouseup events hooked but when i press the usercontrol, automatically its parent control mouseup event is fired. How can I stop this?

Comment: Check whether mouse is covering the child element or not.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MouseUp` event has a bubbling routing strategy, which means it will bubble up from descendants to ancestors. To stop the propagation, mark the event as handled in the child's event handler:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

You can learn more about [event routing strategies on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#routing_strategies).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the basics of `Routed Eventings` to get a better command on how eventing works in WPF. You can check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) link to read further.

The best bet would be identify the `OriginalSource` (the original object that initiated the event), cast it to to your child type and then continue executing your logic.

Eg:

```
void Handler(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        YourChildControl c = e.OriginalSource as YourChildControl;
        if (c != null)
        {
            //this will execute when 
            //do whatever you wanted to do.
        }
        e.Handled = false;
    }
```